# Removing personal data from SVG file

Tags: svg, inkscape

For the first time I needed to perform a *diff* on an SVG file created with Inkscape, because I had a conflict in SVN.

While checking the differences, I noticed that the SVG file contains a lot of personal information. The personal information is about paths used for exporting. The SVG source looks like this:

```
<text ... inkscape:export-filename="<personal information here>" ... />
```

In my case it has a lot of folder names going back to projects I worked for in 2009.

**How can I remove this personal information from Inkscape SVG files?**

Of course I could do it in a text editor manually, but that has some disadvantages:

- it's error-prone. You need to be quite sure what you're doing. There should be a safer way to do it.
- it's time-consuming. There should be a quicker way to do it.
- it might be incomplete. Maybe there is other personal data I have not discovered yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to save the file as an `Optimized SVG` file. This option is available in the `Save As...` dialog dropdown. When you click save a dialog will popup asking you what to remove. Make sure the box `Keep Editor Data` is left **unchecked**.

Comment: I must have missed that one, because it's far down in the options. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Not only did it remove personal data, it also minified my files to half their size. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have a lot of SVGs from different sources, so I was looking for **an automated solution**.

## 1. SVGO (NodeJS, javascript)

There is a very good NPM package: [**SVGO**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo)

Since I use `gulp` as a task-runner, so the [**gulp-svgmin**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgmin) (or [gulp-svgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgo)) is very helpful

## 2. XSLT (transform SVG)

The other automated approach — use XSLT. [Here is an XSL transformation](https://gist.github.com/maxkoryukov/b83af25b8d3739a698909ae648c26f93#file-cleanup-svg-xsl) I have used to cleanup SVG.

This XSLT does the following:

1. removes all `inkscape` and `sodipodi` attributes
2. removes all `inkscape` and `sodipodi` elements
3. removes `metadata` element with all ancestors
4. removes `style` attributes (we use CSS) - only when the variable `preserve-style` is set to `false`

As output you will get the clean SVG file.

### How to run transformation

#### Javascript (gulp build)

If you use [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) as build system, you could use this plugins:

- [gulp-xslt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-xslt)
- or [gulp-saxon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-saxon) *requires the presence of the `saxon.jar` in the system*

#### Python and lxml.etree

Use this short python script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python

import lxml.etree as ET

def clean_file(path, pathto):
    svg1 = ET.parse(path)

    xslt = ET.parse('cleanup-svg.xsl')
    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    svg2 = transform(svg1)
    with open(pathto, 'w') as f:
        f.write(ET.tostring(svg2, pretty_print=True))

clean_file('a.svg', 'b.svg')
```